# How do I complete the transition to the New Input System?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new and recently rewrote the player controller script of a 2D up-and-down Unity game to a new input system. I've already configured all the buttons, but I'm having problems reworking the script for Movement. I don’t understand at all how I can properly rewrite my script to do this. Please, can anyone help me? Thank you in advance!

Script:

```
    using System;
using Data;
using Services.PersistenceProgress;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

namespace Nick
{
    public class NickController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] [Range(1, 5)] private float _speed;

        [SerializeField] private Animator _animator;
        [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D _rigidbody2d;

        private float _horizontalInput;

        private Transform _positionLoadNick;
        private float _verticalInput;
        private Func<float> moveinput;

        public void SetMoveInput(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
        {
            moveinput = context.ReadValue<float>;
        }

        //Universal Input System
        private InputSystem inputSystem;
        void Update()
        {
            _horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            _verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        }

        void Awake(
            {
                inputSystem = new InputSystem();
            }
        )

        private void OnEnable()
        {
            inputSystem.Enable();
        }

        private void OnDisable()
        {
            inputSystem.Disable();
        }

        void FixedUpdate()
        {
            MoveNick();
        }

        private void MoveNick()
        {
            moveInput = inputSystem.Main.Move.ReadValue<float>();
            if (GameFlow.isMovementFreezed)
            {
                _animator.SetInteger("UpDown", 0);
                _animator.SetInteger("Side", 0);
                return;
            }

            Vector2 position = _rigidbody2d.position;
            position.x += _speed * _horizontalInput * Time.deltaTime;
            position.y += _speed * _verticalInput * Time.deltaTime;
            _animator.SetInteger("UpDown", _verticalInput < 0 ? -1 : (int)Math.Ceiling(_verticalInput));
            _animator.SetInteger("Side", _horizontalInput < 0 ? -1 : (int)Math.Ceiling(_horizontalInput));
            _rigidbody2d.MovePosition(position);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: perhaps reading the manual https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.7/manual/index.html will help

Comment: For move you should be reading a Vector2 for the 4 inputs.  Horizontal x and Vertical y, with positive being up & right and negative being down & left.

Comment: @hijinxbassist I don’t quite understand, I beg you to help! How can I put this in code?!

Comment: `Input.GetAxis(..)` returns a float.  Each axis you want to use needs to also be a float.  2 floats can be represented by a Vector2.  So move should be of type Vector2 and you should be reading it as such from code.  x is horizontal, and y is vertical.

Comment: @hijinxbassist ok I did it but it keeps giving me errors :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move should be typed as Vector2.

[image]

Each value of the Vector2 represents an axis.
X is the horizontal axis
Y is the vertical axis

From code, create a Vector2 variable to hold the input.

```
private Vector2 moveInput;
```

Subscribe to the performed event to read the value into the variable.
Subscribe to the canceled event to reset the variable.

```
private void OnEnable()
{
    if (input == null)
    {
        input = new PlayerInput();
    }

    input.Enable();
    input.Main.Move.performed += Move_performed;
    input.Main.Move.canceled += Move_canceled;
}
private void OnDisable()
{
    if (input == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    input.Main.Move.performed -= Move_performed;
    input.Main.Move.canceled -= Move_canceled;
    input.Disable();
}

private void Move_performed(InputAction.CallbackContext obj)
{
    moveInput = obj.ReadValue<Vector2>();
}
private void Move_canceled(InputAction.CallbackContext obj)
{
    moveInput = Vector2.zero;
}
```

Now you can use the `moveInput` variable from wherever, such as `FixedUpdate`.

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    ...
    position.x += _speed * moveInput.x * Time.deltaTime;
    position.y += _speed * moveInput.y * Time.deltaTime;
    ...
}
```